# How to Access a image from another directory? python

Tags: python

I have a python script say "foo_1.py" which resides in folder x and another script foo_2.py which resides in folder y.

Folders x and y are in folder z.

I called a method which belongs to foo_2.py which generates an image in folder y (say img1.png). 
Now what I want is to access this img1.png from foo_1.py.  How is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sys.path[0]` gives you the directory where the current script resides:

```
import sys, os
script_dir = sys.path[0]
img_path = os.path.join(script_dir, '../y/img1.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
img_file = open('../y/img1.png')
```

Comment: This will not work if current directory is not set to the script dir (can happeen if chdir() has been called before)

Comment: yeah, but I kind of doubt, that someone familiar with chdir() would ask this question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What has this to do with Python? Either use an absolute path or a relative path using the wellknown ".." notation. This is Shell basic knowhow.